# Get all virsh configs

Tags: virsh

I've several qemu vm's managed with virsh.
I've already created a backup of the images. Now I want to create a backup of the config files. How can I do that?

The only solution I've figured out so fare is: `virsh dumpxml vmname > bachuk.xml`[see](https://serverfault.com/questions/707544/exporting-libvirtkvm-virtual-machines-to-files#). But this stores only one machine.

Is there a simple way to get just all of the configs with simple commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire libvirt configuration is stored in various files in the `/etc/libvirt` directory, which you can back up via any means you wish.

Comment: hmmm I was looking at `/var/libvirt/...` found some files there. Probably this was an old install dir or it's default. don't know, do you? thx!

Comment: @CuttonEye `/var/lib/libvirt` stores virtual machine backing stores, such as virtual disks, ISO images, boot files, etc. You should also back up this directory, though because the files in here may be very large, you may want a different backup strategy than for the configuration files.